# Eclipse Wildfly integration: Missing webapp resources on server

Tags: eclipse, maven, wildfly, vaadin, jboss-tools

I'm building a java web application with Vaadin, which generates some config files on maven build. For some unknown reasons, only a part of the generated files in `WEB-INF` are present on the when trying to full publish to Wildfly in Eclipse. (In particular, `WEB-INF/classes/META-INF/VAADIN/config/stats.json` is not present which results in an error in the Vaadin application.)

### Several things that were tested

- Maven build does generate the file in the said location.
- Copying the War built by maven directly to /standalone/deployments results in a working application without error.
- After maven build and refresh in eclipse, the generated file is correctly shown in project explorer, indicating a successful refresh (right?)
- Another generated file in the same directory DO get copied (`flow-build-info.json`). The difference between these two files may be, that `flow-build-info.json` exists twice in `target`, in `classes/META-INF/VAADIN...` as well as in `/[final name]/WEB-INF/classes/META-INF...`, while `stats.json` only exists in `/[final name]/WEB-INF/classes/META-INF...`.

### Used versions

- Eclipse version: 21.12 & 21.9
- JBoss AS, WildFly & EAP Server Tools: 3.9.106.v20210618-2025
- Wildfly 17, 20, 22
- Vaadin 14.7.5

Answer (score 2):

I found out the problem: Maven build generates the Vaadin files just fine. However, if a maven update is executed afterwards in Eclipse before publishing to the server, the maven update would modify the `target/classes` directory. This modification somehow removes all files but the `flow-build-info.json` (still don't understand this part). This results in the missing resources after publishing.

So basically, maven build -> refresh in eclipse -> NO MAVEN UPDATE -> full publish works.